# Cómo instalar el SDK de mercado pago en mi tienda online con PHP

Tags: mercadopago

quiero preguntarles como poder integrar el SDK de mercadopago en una tienda online con PHP  sin framework. Actualmente he descargado el composer en mi computador pero no sé cómo crear la interacción con la compra del cliente ¿conocerán de algún curso para poder realizarlo? o si me pueden ayudar con su experiencia. Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La opcion mas facil es seguir los pasos que te indican en la pagina. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo basico para el pago de un producto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pago Mercadopago</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Mercadopago pago:</h2>

    <?php

    include_once "vendor/autoload.php";  //Aqui coloca la ruta en donde descargaste el sdk de mercadopago

    MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken(''); // Ya que vas a hacer pruebas de pago, aqui tu access token de prueba, luego puedes agregar el token de produccion

    // Crea un objeto de preferencia
    $preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

    // Crea un ítem en la preferencia
    $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
    $item->title = 'Producto 1';
    $item->quantity = 1;
    $item->unit_price = 300; //Detalle aca, si tu previamente tienes configurado en tu cuenta que eres de algun pais que no maneje decimales en el valor, el valor debe ser entero, sino mercadopago arrojara error
    $preference->items = array($item);
    $preference->save();

    ?>

    <form action="/procesar-pago" method="POST">
        <script src="https://www.mercadopago.cl/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js" data-preference-id="<?php echo $preference->id; ?>">
        </script>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Con esto ya seria lo basico de lo basico para pagar un producto, ya despues deberias buscar un metodo dinamico en el cual agregar mas productos, el nombre del cliente, personalizar los items, etc. Espero que sirva de algo.